# Oracle: Select Milliseconds from Timestamp Type that Defaults with SYSTIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timestamp, milliseconds, systimestamp

I have a column with `TIMESTAMP` type in my Oracle Database. The `default` column value is `SYSTIMESTAMP`.

I want to `SELECT` **milliseconds** `FROM` the TIMESTAMP column. I use the query below without success:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (MY_TIMESTAMP, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF') AS MY_TIMESTAMP
FROM MY_TABLE

-- Result: 20-12-2015 15:23:28.
```

As you see the result does not have any milliseconds and it is empty. If I change the query with `.FF4` then it results `.0000`.

How can I SELECT the column with milliseconds?

Comment: What is the exact data type of the column? For TIMESTAMP you can specify the precision

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It is TIMESTAMP. Where can I specify the precision?

Comment: Please run this query and apend it's result to the question: `select column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and column_name = 'MY_TIMESTAMP'`. The query gives information about datatype and fractional seconds precision of the column in the table. Could be that the column has too short precision and doesn't store fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision for timestamp columns can be set up by

`TIMESTAMP [(fractional_seconds_precision)]`.

In your case for 4 it's:

```
create table my_table
(id number,
  my_TIMESTAMP timestamp(4) default SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

You can check your current precision by:

```
select column_name, data_scale from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and column_name = 'MY_TIMESTAMP';
```

Here is sample in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/115ab/1/1)

The display can be change by:

```
 alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MI:SS.FF9';
```